# Kalman Filter with log(X) as a state variable in Python

Tags: python, kalman-filter

I'm trying to estimate an (extended) Kalman Filter where one of the state variables (say x_{3}) would be modeled as log(x_{3}) to ensure its non-negativity.

Here is the code for a plain extended Kalman Filter:

```
# Loop over time
for t in range(T):
    
    # Predict state vector
    Xt_1[:, [t]] = muP + thetaP @ Xt[:, [t]]
    
    # MSE matrix state equation
    Pt_1[:, :, t] = thetaP @ Pt[:, :, t] @ thetaP.T + Sigmae
    
    # Measurement equation
    y_hat = A + B.T @ Xt_1[:, [t]]
    # fitting errors
    errors = yields[[t], :] - y_hat
    
    # estimatge Jacobian
    H = compute_jacobian(Xt_1, t)
    # compute F
    F = np.matrix(H @ Pt_1[:, :, t] @ H.T) + Sigmaz

    # Kalman gain
    K = Pt_1[:, :, t] @ B @ np.linalg.inv(F)
    # state vector
    Xt[:, [t + 1]] = Xt_1[:, [t]] + K @ errors
    # MSE matrix state equation
    Pt[:, :, t + 1] = (np.eye(3) - K @ B.T) @ Pt_1[:, :, t]
```

Basically I don't know what to modify, outside modifying the Jacobian and providing a log(x_{3}) initial value, if I want Xt=(x_{1},x_{2},log(x_{3})) instead of Xt=(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}). Do I need to amend the state equation at the predict and update stages?

Any idea?

Comment: Can you give more context on what are you trying to achieve? Do you just want to enforce non-negativity of `x3`? If so, why?

Comment: Hi Marat, yes in my model I need x3 to remain positive. One trick commonly used is to model log(x3) instead of x3. I figured how to modify the Jacobian matrix H accordingly, but I'm not sure how to amend the other Kalman Filter equations...